# Trying to run an existing application and getting (Psych::SyntaxError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, ruby-2.1

The application is running on the a web server properly and I tried to run it locally and I am getting these errors. 
Any idea what the issue might be? I am new to Ruby, so please excuse me if this is a simple question

```
..../.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse': (<unknown>): could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 18 column 3 (Psych::SyntaxError)
from ..../.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse_stream'
from ..../.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:318:in `parse'
from ..../.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:245:in `load'
from ..../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:115:in `database_configuration'
from ..../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:75:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
from ..../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
from ..../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
from ..../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `block in on_load'
from ..../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `each'
from ..../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `on_load'
from ..../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:74:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
from ..../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from ..../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from ..../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from ..../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
from ..../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from ..../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
from ..../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from ..../appname/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from ..../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from ..../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from ..../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from ..../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from ..../appname/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
from ..../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
from ..../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
from ..../appname/config.ru:1:in `new'
from ..../appname/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
from ..../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
from ..../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
from ..../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
from ..../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
from ..../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
from .../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
from .../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
from ../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
from .../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from .../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that vendors are not found.

Try to run `bundle` command to install it on your local machine.

Comment: Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

Comment: And what does the console say after a `bundle show activerecord` for instance?

Comment: ../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-3.2.3

Comment: any thoughts what the issue might be?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is helpful but I also get the following Warning

DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from  at .../appname/Rakefile:7)